# "Yum yum pig's bum"

Tags: poetry, textual-history, oral-tradition

I saw a vernacular poem that appears to have been passed down and passed around in various parts of the UK. A couple of different versions:

> Yum yum
> Pig's bum
> Wrap it up
> In chewing gum
>
> Have a slice
> Very nice!
>
> Yum yum
> Pig's bum

My first question is why wrap it up in chewing gum?

This version is [purportedly](http://mind-motion.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-full-english-17.html) Irish:

> Yum, yum, pig's bum,
> Cabbage and potatoes.

[Another one](http://mind-motion.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-full-english-17.html):

> Yum yum bubble gum
> stick it up the teachers bum
> if it sticks
> pull her tits
> and turn it into weetabix.

Where did this verse originate?

Comment: Why wrap it up in chewing gum? The answer might be as simple as "because it rhymes", without bothering about whether it makes sense or not.

Comment: Also referred on [Yahoo Answers](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080307044415AAH1ClR), someone's [blog](http://mind-motion.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-full-english-17.html), and [BBC Strictly Come Dancing](https://twitter.com/bbcstrictly/status/278205189784223744?lang=en). The usual source for this would be [the Opies' *Oxford Dictionary of Nursery Rhymes*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?q=editions:ISBN0198600887&id=NihcugEACAAJ), but sadly I don't own a copy to check.

Comment: Yum yum bubble gum, stick it up your mother's bum. If it sticks, pull down her knick-knicks. Recited to me by my children in Bristol c. 1985.

Comment: Captain Cook did a "pook" behind the cabin door. The cat came up, and licked it up, and said "Can I have some more?" Told to me c. 1957 by another kid (London).

Comment: My mum always says > Yum yum pig's bum If I have a party you can’t come, bread without butter, tea without rum, yum yum pig's bum

Comment: Yum yum bubble gum Stick it up your mothers bum
If it’s brown, pull it down
Bubble gum, bubble gum A child if the 50s/60s

Comment: @Rob: Also (but with _when_ instead of _if_) recorded in Hampshire in 1983, according to Steve Roud's The Lore of the Playground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dorothy Baker's *The Street*, a 1951 novel about working-class people in the West Midlands, the rhyme is reproduced as:

> Ham, ham, pig's bum,
> When I have a party
> You shan't come.
> Bread without butter
> Tea without sugar
> Ham, ham, pig's bum.

(Recited by a schoolgirl to her teacher when asked if anybody in the class could say some poetry.)

Ham and pig's bum are obviously semantically connected. I'd imagine that subsequent variants are arising as children playing with sounds and finding rhymes for "bum". That is certainly the most enticing word to keep in the song and to highlight by wordplay. In the sibling answer by annie is an intermediate form, where we have a rhyme for "bum" with "rum" instead of "sugar", plus the replacement of "ham" with "yum" for yet another rhyme.

The root imagery here is common to many nursery rhymes - punishment based on denying food, or some other treat such as a party invitation. A 1794 version (the oldest recorded version) of [the old woman who lived in a shoe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_was_an_Old_Woman_Who_Lived_in_a_Shoe) is:

> There was an old woman who lived in a shoe.
> She had so many children, she didn't know what to do.
> She gave them some broth without any bread;
> She whipp'd all their bums, and sent them to bed.

I'm presenting this not as a strict precursor, but as evidence that there are lots of songs and rhymes for children which include the same sorts of words and ideas.

I think the "pig's bum" rhymes seem more adapted to playground chants or skipping rhymes, given the rhythm and nonsensical content, and especially the use of a taboo word. But the 1951 example, in addition, is perhaps a little closer to conventional nursery rhymes. It may not be possible to find a real answer for where this particular one *originated*, given the informal nature of the material.